# Need to add VAR % Column for 2022 vs 2021 numbers, it also needs to be included in the Grand Total bar at the bottom

Tags: excel, pivot-table, measure

[Report Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GoiT.jpg)

I am trying to add a Column at the end of this pivot table that will show VAR % 2022 vs 2021. I will also need the calculation to occur in the Grand Total bar at the bottom so we can see the VAR % by account, plus by Grand Total. This report is generated using Power Pivot so I cannot use the Calculated Field option. I attempted to create a Measures in the Power Pivot, but what happens when I add that Measure to my Pivot Table is it ignores all Slicers/Filters and shows every single account in the Data Table when the filtered drill down should only be about 30 accounts.
Any idea on how I can achieve this? I would love to use Measures so I can also attach a KPI but for some reason using Measures makes it like I didn't even have a filter working.
Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A small copiable example with expected results would be helpful.

Comment: I added a link to the picture of the report. VAR % is what is needed at the end of this report including in the Grand Total bar at the bottom.